# Insertion to map (with custom compare functor) runs into invalid node/address

Tags: c++, stl

Im debugging a memory corruption issue and would like to get some help to figure out the problem.

We have a map with a custom comparator (functor that does the comparison between the map objects). We have a function that inserts  pair into the map. 
The map is cleared at the beginning of the function, before entries are inserted into it.

Access to the map is serialized.

The problem is that while inserting an entry into the map, the insert (c++ stl insert) functions invokes the compare function with an invalid object. The object's address points to the size of the map (memory region where the size of the map is stored).
I guess, somehow the Rbtree insert finds this address in the Rbtree. When the  pair is obtained, we figure out that its invalid and panic.

This code is executed a number of times , but the corruption itself has shown up just a couple of times.

I've checked that the code is serialized. Im not sure if there's an issue in the way Im using the custom compare function.

Here's how I've used the map

```
map<K, V, CmpObj> *map_obj

map_obj = new map<K, V, CmpObj>(list); // List of keys/criteria to sort map objects

class CmpObj {
    list<KeyCriteria*> sort_klist_;

    public:
    CmpObj(list<KeyCriteria*> sort_klist)
   {
       sort_klist_ = sort_klist;
   }
   bool operator() (const K& k1, const K& k2);
};
```

So in summary:

1. Custom compare function is used for the map.
2. Map insert (RbTree insert) runs into a node/address which holds the size of the map. This happens after a couple of successful insertions.
3. Access to the map is serialized.
4. The problem has happened a very few times.

Comment: Perhaps your comparison functor doesn't satisfy map's requirements. Too bad you haven't shown it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is C++. Push `new` to the back of your mind. Create things on the stack or use `std::unique_ptr`. Use `std::shared_ptr` for when ownership is actually shared.

Comment: Your `CmpObj` constructor parameter `sort_klist` is a copy of the passed argument and then you copy it to the member `sort_klist_`. The constructor parameter should probably be `list<KeyCriteria*> const &sort_klist`.

Comment: Make sure the comparison function implements strict weak ordering.